# Debugger port not opening

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, intellij-13

For some reason when i run my Spring application from intellij some task is not being executed because of which my stub server responds with a error.So i tried to start it through a pre-written go script in my project and it worked.
But now attaching debugger becomes a problem because i have started my application from terminal.

I tried doing a remote debug by setting a remote configuration in intellij and setting  the port as 8000 but i keep getting the error "Connection refused"

Below is the remote configuration screenshot:
[Remote config screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUG6h.png)

Is this the correct approach to attach debugger for an app started through terminal?

Command to start in debug mode:

`gradle bootRun
-Dagentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8080`

Answer (score 0):

The alternative and easier way is opening the `Run anything` window (ctrl/command + shift + A) and then searching for `attach debugger` action. IntelliJ will try to find any processes that have debugger attached, and will display a list from which you can choose which process to attach to.

Provided that you get `java.lang.module.FindException`, you might also try to run `gradle bootJar` and then run the generated jar (in `build/libs` directory) file by

`java "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8080"  --add-exports java.base/jdk.hotspot.agent=ALL-UNNAMED -jar my_jar.jar`

Please also note that finding a way to tell gradle to run your jar (in bootRun task) correctly is the more correct way.

Comment: But doing so doesnt attach to a process started through terminal.It only list the processes started through intellij

Comment: Can you edit your post and the command that you have used to start your java process outside of IntelliJ ?

Comment: I have tried to add a remote configuration(as shown in the attached screenshot) but it fails with the error Connection refused on port 8000.Not sure if thats the correct way to attach to a process.

Comment: I mean the command you entered in the terminal to start the application. `But now attaching debugger becomes a problem because i have started my application from terminal`. Please edit and add that terminal command.

Comment: I tried again with the attach process approach that you suggested and it now lists the process running in terminal.But it fails with the below error:
java.lang.module.FindException: Module jdk.hotspot.agent not found

Comment: Please add the information that I have requested, otherwise I will not be able to help you any further.

Comment: I get this error now:


```Unrecognized option: --add-exports
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.```

Comment: You have to run java 9 or above to use add exports and you have to both compile and run with that option. Otherwise try using java 8

Comment: Tried Java 8 for another project and it throws the below error:
```Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach symbolicator to the process at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal.attach0(Native Method) at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal.access$100(BsdDebuggerLocal.java:65) at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal$1AttachTask.doit(BsdDebuggerLocal.java:278)```

Looks like i need to move on, have been stuck with consecutive errors for a long time now :)