# Unable to attach debugger to process

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

Attaching debugger to running app fails with the below error:

```
40:1556: execution error: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module jdk.hotspot.agent not found(1)
```

Manually adding exports with the generated jar also fails.

The below error is thrown when I try from a different system:

```
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach symbolicator to the process     
at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal.attach0(Native Method)     
at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal.access$100(BsdDebuggerLocal.java:65)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.bsd.BsdDebuggerLocal$1AttachTask.doit(BsdDebuggerLocal.java:278)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugger port not opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58581547/debugger-port-not-opening)

Comment: Should be fixed in JDK 9: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8160376